# FlutterError: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator when using Flutter local notification plugin

Tags: flutter, notifications

I have a sports app, so now I am setting reminders notification for a match, so I am using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin to get those notifications. So, now yes, I can set the reminder notification and I am getting the notification, so now, when I click the notification, I want it to land on that specific match page hence I specified the eventId but now it just opens the app. Please check my code below:

```
class ReminderService with ChangeNotifier {
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  List<PendingNotificationRequest>? _pendingNotificationRequests;
  RemindersViewModel? reminderViewModel;
  LoadingStatus _status = LoadingStatus.idle;

  bool isTimeupdate = false;
  ReminderService(BuildContext context) {
    _pendingNotificationRequests = [];
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    _initialiseLocalNotificationsPlugin(context);
  }

  List<PendingNotificationRequest>? get pendingNotificationRequests => _pendingNotificationRequests;

  bool get hasReminders => _pendingNotificationRequests!.isNotEmpty;

  Future<void> _initialiseLocalNotificationsPlugin(BuildContext context) async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings(androidAppIcon);
    const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );
    final bool? isInitialised = await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
        final String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;

        switch (notificationResponse.notificationResponseType) {
          case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification:
            //  selectNotificationStream.add(notificationResponse.payload);
            onReminderNotificationOpened(payload, context);

            break;
          case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotificationAction:
            break;
        }
      },

      //onSelectNotification: onReminderNotificationOpened,
    );
    if (isInitialised!) {
      _pendingNotificationRequests = await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> onReminderNotificationOpened(
    String? data,
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    final Map map = json.decode(data!);
    final String? eventId = map['eventId'];
    if (eventId != null) {
      Navigator.push( //the error throws here
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewUpcomingMatchPageWidget(
                  sport: '',
                  title: '',
                  icon: '',
                  documentId: '',
                  isPostponed: false,
                  eventName: '',
                  eventId: eventId,
                  feedId: '',
                  eventDateStart: DateTime.now(),
                  location: '',
                  headerBackgroundImage: const SizedBox(),
                  subStatusName: '',
                )),
      );
    }
    // await removeReminderByEventId(eventId);
    // notifyListeners();
  }
```

where I have declared this class on my providers.dart class:

```
 ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ReminderService(context),
    ),
```

Okay, as you can see on the code, I have included the navigation code so now I am getting the error: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator so I can't find where I am getting it wrong, can you please assist.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan can you please assist?